# Avoid sidebar overlapping content on tumblr with CSS positioning

Tags: css, positioning, tumblr, sidebar

I'm having problems avoiding my sidebar to overlap the main content of my blog on tumblr. I am using a premade template on tumblr which i have modified. The only ways I can position my sidebar in the top right corner, is by using an absolute or fixed position:

```
#sidebar{
position:fixed;
top:20px;
right:20px;
}
```

When using e.g. relative, the sidebar position itself in the bottom after my main content.

My page is built up like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>

</body>
```

Click [here](http://www.itflowsmusic.tumblr.com) to see the page.
I tried putting my sidebar inside the page div, but there's a constraint on the width, which I would like to keep. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would you like to happen when screen is shrunken to a width that causes overlap?

Comment: I'd like the sidebar and page to shrink when that happens. I'd like to avoid using any javascript if that is possible. elseway, any similar solution would be just as great.

Comment: What is the smallest width screen you are looking to accommodate?  For example, if I shrink my browser window to the width of an iPhone then your solution of "just shrink the sidebar" is not feasible because it would have to be extremely narrow.

Comment: I see your point, I think I'll have to think about that and read a bit about webpages and screen resolutions, before I can define it further. I'm definetely not trying to make it suitable for mobile platforms however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your latest comment, this should help your problem:

You could just set a min-width on your page, rearrange your markup a little, and remove some styles on the sidebar. If you leave everything like it is now, then the following will help:

1. Set `min-width: 1250px;` on your `body` tag
2. Move the `sidebar` element to before the `page` element
3. Remove `position: fixed;` from the `sidebar` element

This will prevent the menu from overlapping the page content and will add a horizontal scrollbar to the page when the user's window is less than 1250px.  If you want to support a smaller min-width or if you have a problem with the background image becoming not centered at small resolutions, then minor modifications will be necessary.